# Bash 'if' variations

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

Is there any difference between the following if statements in bash?

```
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" -a  -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
```

Which should I prefer? Are any of those "better"?

Comment: The first one seems clearer for sure

Comment: Note that `if` is irrelevant for the question, you can use `[` even without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-a` isn't available in all older (pre-POSIX) shells, so you should prefer `&&` when trying to be portable.

That said, if you're ONLY supporting bash, use its built-in `[[ ]]` facility, which allows `&&` *within* a test rather than only outside it (and, as an added bonus, makes quoting optional):

```
[[ -z $debian_chroot && -r /etc/debian_chroot ]]
```

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 3):

The first is preferred. See the "Application Usage" section of the [POSIX standard for the `test` built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for the reason. In brief, `-a` is an extension marked as obsolete due to ambiguities in meaning for certain expressions.